# Switching from bottle.template to mako

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bottle, mako

Because I need to define a function in a tpl file, I need to switch from bottle.

My question is two-fold:

1. In general, are my existing tpls still usable?
2. How do I change my return in my server.py?

Here is the existing code:

```
@bottle.route('/showDevice')
def device_view():
    device_id = bottle.request.query.id
    result = lib.crud_ops.find_by_id(collection, device_id)
    return bottle.template('device_view.tpl', {'device':result})
```

I have tried adding a few things:

```
 myTemplate = Template(filename='device_view.tpl')
 myTemplate.render(device=result)
```

but Mako doesn't know where my 'device_view.tpl' file is, and I'm not sure if 'device' is being passed in as a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define functions to be used in the template even with bottle's `SimpleTemplate`:

```
def func():
  ...

def device_view():
  return bottle.template('device_view.tpl', {'device':result, 'func':func})

{{func(data)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I accepted presveva's answer, but I wanted to add that I was able to use functions in bottle. I just had to update from the old version of bottle-0.10 to bottle-0.12.

I called it like this:

```
%variable_name = py_package_name.python_file.function_name(input_variable)
```